# What happens to those questions which had a bounty and whose answers are accepted by the OP?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties, accepted-answer

What happens to those questions which had a bounty and whose answers are accepted by the OP? Where do they go? Unless I favorite all such questions, I would have no way of seeing "previously bountied questions" which have been "answered". Having such questions marked specially would be a great asset because bounty questions are no ordinary questions, they are one step (or more steps) beyond ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having such questions marked specially would be a great asset because bounty questions are no ordinary questions

I have no idea why that would be true; normally bounties are on questions that haven't gotten a satisfactory answer. Either that's because they're really hard, really obscure, or because they were confusing/poorly written and nobody wanted to bother, but the OP put a bounty on it because they were desperate.

In any case, you can use SEDE to list all posts that have had a bounty: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1508/all-bounties

Comment: Thanks, in many cases (though not always, like you said), the question is hard, that's why a bounty was put, so finding the answers made to such hard questions would be helpful, isn't it?